# Unexpected behavior with foverlaps on floating point intervals

Tags: r, data.table

Here is an example where `foverlaps(...)` seems to be finding matches that do not overlap. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

The problem in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26950123/how-to-show-frequencies-in-discrete-categories-with-range-data-in-r) seems like an excellent opportunity to use `foverlaps(...)` in the data.table package. The datasets below are from that post.

```
dinosaurs <- structure(list(GENUS = structure(1:3, .Label = c("Abydosaurus", "Achelousaurus", "Acheroraptor"), class = "factor"), ma_max = c(109, 84.9, 70.6), ma_min = c(94.3, 70.6, 66.043), ma_mid = c(101.65, 77.75, 68.3215)), .Names = c("GENUS", "ma_max", "ma_min", "ma_mid"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
stages    <- structure(list(Stage = structure(c(13L, 19L, 17L, 21L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 16L, 14L, 20L, 7L, 23L, 12L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 10L, 22L, 11L, 18L, 9L, 15L), .Label = c("Aalenian", "Albian", "Aptian", "Bajocian", "Barremian", "Bathonian", "Berriasian", "Callovian", "Campanian", "Cenomanian", "Coniacian", "Hauterivian", "Hettangian", "Kimmeridgian", "Maastrichtian", "Oxfordian", "Pliensbachian", "Santonian", "Sinemurian", "Tithonian", "Toarcian", "Turonian", "Valanginian"), class = "factor"),ma_max = c(201.6, 197, 190, 183, 176, 172, 168, 165, 161, 156, 151, 145.5, 140, 136, 130, 125, 112, 99.6, 93.5, 89.3, 85.8, 83.5, 70.6), ma_min = c(197, 190, 183, 176, 172, 168, 165, 161, 156, 151, 145.5, 140, 136, 130, 125, 112, 99.6, 93.5, 89.3, 85.8, 83.5, 70.6, 66.5), ma_mid = c(199.3, 193.5, 186.5, 179.5, 174, 170, 166.5, 163, 158.5, 153.5, 148.25, 142.75, 138, 133, 127.5, 118.5, 105.8, 96.55, 91.4, 87.55, 84.65, 77.05, 68.05)), .Names = c("Stage", "ma_max", "ma_min", "ma_mid"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
dinosaurs
#           GENUS ma_max ma_min   ma_mid
# 1   Abydosaurus  109.0 94.300 101.6500
# 2 Achelousaurus   84.9 70.600  77.7500
# 3  Acheroraptor   70.6 66.043  68.3215
head(stages)
#           Stage ma_max ma_min ma_mid
# 1    Hettangian  201.6    197  199.3
# 2    Sinemurian  197.0    190  193.5
# 3 Pliensbachian  190.0    183  186.5
# 4      Toarcian  183.0    176  179.5
# 5      Aalenian  176.0    172  174.0
# 6      Bajocian  172.0    168  170.0
```

The goal is to find the number of dinosaur genera which were present in each geological stage.

```
library(data.table)   # 1.9.4
setDT(dinosaurs)[,ma_mid:=NULL]
setDT(stages)[,ma_mid:=NULL]
setkey(dinosaurs,ma_min,ma_max)
foverlaps(stages,dinosaurs,type="any",nomatch=0)
#            GENUS ma_max ma_min         Stage i.ma_max i.ma_min
# 1:   Abydosaurus  109.0 94.300        Albian    112.0     99.6
# 2:   Abydosaurus  109.0 94.300    Cenomanian     99.6     93.5
# 3: Achelousaurus   84.9 70.600     Coniacian     89.3     85.8
# 4: Achelousaurus   84.9 70.600     Santonian     85.8     83.5
# 5:  Acheroraptor   70.6 66.043     Campanian     83.5     70.6
# 6: Achelousaurus   84.9 70.600     Campanian     83.5     70.6
# 7:  Acheroraptor   70.6 66.043 Maastrichtian     70.6     66.5
# 8: Achelousaurus   84.9 70.600 Maastrichtian     70.6     66.5
```

This is mostly correct, but look at row 3. This seems to assert that the Cenomanian stage, from 85.8 to 89.3 million years ago, overlaps with Achelousaurus, which lived from 70.6 to 84.9 million years ago. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please try it with `1.9.5`? `devtools::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes=FALSE)`.

Comment: I tried this but got, eventually, `ERROR: compilation failed for package 'data.table'
...Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘GenomicRanges’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1) 
`

Comment: Also, it looks like someone else did the same thing (see the link in the question) and did not get this problem.

Comment: They were using 1.9.5 though. Any idea why the install from github onto Windows would fail?

Comment: Any potential solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+install_github+windows+Command+failed) (as suggested by Matt [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation))?

Comment: Restarted RStudio and the install worked. Finally.

Comment: jlhoward, awesome! Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On 1.9.5, I get this:

```
#            GENUS ma_max ma_min         Stage i.ma_max i.ma_min
# 1:   Abydosaurus  109.0 94.300        Albian    112.0     99.6
# 2:   Abydosaurus  109.0 94.300    Cenomanian     99.6     93.5
# 3: Achelousaurus   84.9 70.600     Santonian     85.8     83.5
# 4:  Acheroraptor   70.6 66.043     Campanian     83.5     70.6
# 5: Achelousaurus   84.9 70.600     Campanian     83.5     70.6
# 6:  Acheroraptor   70.6 66.043 Maastrichtian     70.6     66.5
# 7: Achelousaurus   84.9 70.600 Maastrichtian     70.6     66.5
```

Most likely floating point bug fixed in 1.9.5 in [this commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/62bff083d764956e863c6b08b2573852906ffce9). Would be great if you could verify this as well.